# Is it possible to run ASP.NET Core application in IBM Containers for Bluemix?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, ibm-cloud

What would the Dockerfile look like in order to run an ASP.NET Core (formerly ASP.NET 5) app in a Bluemix container?

I tried https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/dev/samples/1.0.0-rc1-update1/HelloWeb/Dockerfile and wasn't able to access my app on my public IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kestrel is listening on localhost but Docker is forwarding requests to the container's 0.0.0.0 network interface. You can fix this by adding `--server.urls` to the ENTRYPOINT instruction:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "web", "--server.urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

Also IBM Containers for Bluemix may be blocking the port you are trying to expose, for example 5000. You can fix this by running your image with the `-p` option:

```
cf ic run -p <public IP>:80:5000 registry.ng.bluemix.net/<namespace>/<image name>
```

Then in a web browser your app would be available at `http://<public IP>`.